# The variation of the DAC output is abnormal

Tags: microcontroller, pic, adc, microchip, dac

### Description of the situation

I want to output the data from the ADC to the DAC.

I use an ADC from Microchip dsPIC33EV128GM104-E / PT and I am using 12 bits.

Microchip MCP4922T-E / ST is used and 12bit is used.

I created the driver code using mcc code generator and it works fine.

I am using 1 DAC and Vref is using 5V.

The gain of the DAC is used as 1.

We tested that the data received from the ADC comes in normally.

### Used chipset

- ADC : Microchip dsPIC33EV128GM104-E/PT
- DAC : Microchip MCP4922T-E/ST

### The problem

The DAC output data goes up and down and then suddenly increases significantly.

When the output value of the DAC is confirmed by the oscilloscope, it suddenly increases from 600mv to 900mv. It also increases from 1.1v to 1.8v.

Also, the output value decreases and increases.

I wrote a code that raises 0 ~ 4095 as a test code and the same symptom appears.

### The question

I wonder about three points.

1. When does this happen?
2. The value of the DAC increases like a staircase, but can this be the same thing?
3. Does the DAC's SDO, SCK, and CS have 22R resistors that could be a problem?

### Resources

dsPIC33 https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/dsPIC33EV128GM104

DAC
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22250a.pdf

### Edited

When we checked with the oscilloscope we found that the value increased significantly when the first bit changed.

0000 1111 1111 -> 0001 0000 0000

When the lower bit changes, the value is incremented and descended.

Comment: Toggle each bit and measure change like a square wave 12 times.  Then do ramps expecting like sawtooth waveform.  Large transitions may indicate swapped or reversed bytes . Smaller transitions might indicate Vref crosstalk from number of logic 0's. Yours is unusual.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 
I toggled each bit to test it with an oscilloscope. The same symptoms are repeated.

Comment: What symptoms. Is there any correlation to bits?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 What I've found is that the voltage rises significantly each time the front of the bit changes.

Comment: That’s not very measureable

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 
I solved this problem. Raised the resistance of 22R to 1KR. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need any resistors on an SPI interface.

Comment: @Mike 
I changed the resistance and it worked. I did a test, but it is normal.

Comment: See Page 27 of the datasheet for a typical connection. An SPI interface don't need any resistors like an I2C interface

Comment: Series R is to dampen series L (1 nH/mm) unless controlled impedance, maybe yours must be excessive , mike is right, but you might using jumpers with ESL